# Why is mainnet-beta program deploy taking so much time?

Tags: anchor, solana-cli, deploy, mainnet

Why is mainnet-beta program deploy taking so much time?
It took 6 hours to complete 1.0% of the whole process
I use
solana-cli version: 1.18.3
anchor version: anchor-cli 0.29.0
solana cluster-version : 1.18.4

plz help me

Comment: How many block-confirmations do you require in your code to let it be the status "deployed"?

Answer (score 1):

Its currently very hard to deploy programs to mainnet, because the CLI does not have priority fees. The problem is being worked on here: https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave/pull/144 In the meantime you can try fork solana and add more retries: https://twitter.com/sssionggg/status/1767961870269559027 or use solana playground: https://twitter.com/acheroncrypto/status/1768423506843168994?t=N1TxcxNhNIJ4dChFUOVxzg&s=19

Answer (score 1):

I solve this problem by add flag --with-compute-unit-price 1 (you can change 1 to any unit price you one, 1  = 1 microlamport). This flag will add priority fee for all your deployed tx.
try this

> solana program deploy ./target/deploy/<..>.so --with-compute-unit-price 5